# SEH Handlers using RtlAddFunctionTable

Tags: winapi, gcc, error-handling, 64-bit, seh

I've been trying to setup SEH on x64 windows using gcc by calling the `RtlAddFunctionTable`. Unfortunately, the API call returns success but my handler doesn't seem to ever be called. And I can't find out what's wrong. My small example is:

```
EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION catchDivZero( struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD* rec
                                  , void* arg1 __attribute__((unused))
                                  , struct _CONTEXT* ctxt __attribute__((unused))
                                  , void* arg2 __attribute__((unused))
                                  )
{
    printf("Exception will be handled!\n");
    return ExceptionContinueSearch;
}

HMODULE GetCurrentModule()
{ // NB: XP+ solution!
    HMODULE hModule = NULL;
    GetModuleHandleEx(
        GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
        (LPCTSTR)GetCurrentModule,
        &hModule);

    return hModule;
}

typedef struct {
    UINT8  Version : 3;
    UINT8  Flags : 5;
    UINT8  SizeOfProlog;
    UINT8  CountOfUnwindCodes;
    UINT8  FrameRegister : 4;
    UINT8  FrameRegisterOffset : 4;
    ULONG  ExceptionHandler;
} UNWIND_INFO;

/* Hack, for bug in ld.  Will be removed soon.  */
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define __ImageBase __MINGW_LSYMBOL(_image_base__)
#endif

/* Get the end of the text section.  */
extern char etext[] asm("etext");

/* Get the base of the module.       */
/* This symbol is defined by ld.     */
extern IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;

static UNWIND_INFO info[1];
static RUNTIME_FUNCTION handlers[1];

#define base (ULONG)((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase)

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    HMODULE hModule = GetCurrentModule();

    MODULEINFO mi;
    GetModuleInformation(hProcess, hModule, &mi, sizeof(mi));

    printf( "Module: 0x%.8X (0x%.8X) 0x%.8X |0x%.8X| [0x%.8X] {0x%.8X}\n\n"
          , mi.lpBaseOfDll
          , base
          , (char*)etext
          , mi.SizeOfImage
          , &catchDivZero
          , (ULONG)(&catchDivZero - base)
          );

    printf("Building UNWIND_INFO..\n");

    info[0].Version             = 1;
    info[0].Flags               = UNW_FLAG_EHANDLER;
    info[0].SizeOfProlog        = 0;
    info[0].CountOfUnwindCodes  = 0;
    info[0].FrameRegister       = 0;
    info[0].FrameRegisterOffset = 0;
    info[0].ExceptionHandler    = (ULONG)(&catchDivZero - base);

    printf("Created UNWIND_INFO at {0x%.8X}\n", info[0].ExceptionHandler);

    printf("Building SEH handlers...\n");

    handlers[0].BeginAddress = 0;
    handlers[0].EndAddress   = (ULONG)(etext - base);
    handlers[0].UnwindData   = (ULONG)((char*)info - base);

    printf("Adding SEH handlers to .pdata..\n");
    printf("Handler Unwind: 0x%.8X\n", &info);
    printf( "Handler Info:: s: 0x%.8X, e: 0x%.8X, u: 0x%.8X\n"
          , handlers[0].BeginAddress
          , handlers[0].EndAddress
          , handlers[0].UnwindData
          );

    if (RtlAddFunctionTable(handlers, 1, (DWORD64)base))
    {
        printf("Hook succeeded.\nTesting..\n");
        printf("Things to do: %i\n", 12 / 0);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Hook failed\n");
        DWORD result = GetLastError();
        printf("Error code: 0x%.8X\n", result);
    }
}
```

However when called the output I get is:

```
> .\a.exe
Module: 0x00400000 (0x00400000) 0x00402FF0 |0x00022000| [0x00401530] {0x00001530}

Building UNWIND_INFO..
Created UNWIND_INFO at {0x00001530}
Building SEH handlers...
Adding SEH handlers to .pdata..
Handler Unwind: 0x00407030
Handler Info:: s: 0x00000000, e: 0x00002FF0, u: 0x00007030
Hook succeeded.
Testing..
```

The message in my handler is never printed.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [RtlAddFunctionTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680588.aspx): *"Function tables are used on 64-bit Windows to determine how to unwind or walk the stack."* 64-bit Windows uses table-based exception handling. 32-bit Windows uses frame-based exception handling.

Comment: For x86 you'll have to set up an `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION` object on the stack to enqueue an exception frame into the chain of exception handlers. [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx) offers insight into the SEH implementation of 32-bit Windows.

Comment: Sorry, a typo in the description, this is for x64, I'll correct the description

Comment: Are you using mingw-w64?  I believe they already have support for SEH built in: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-win32/seh/  I don't know much about SEH myself, but if you want to look at their source where they call RtlAddFunctionTable to compare it with yours: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt_handler.c#l51

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I am using mingw-w64, I've had a look at that before and the virtualbox source code which also sets some SEH handlers but couldn't find any real difference. They're representing the structures slightly differently, like combining Version and Flags into one variable. I will take another look at it and try exactly what they're doing. But I suspect that because the function is returning OK that the structure is correct.

Comment: Does anyone know If there's a tool that works on x64 handler to list all SEH handlers on a region of memory? I see plenty for x86 but not for x64. would windbg's .fnent work for x64?

Answer (score 3):

RtlAddFunctionTable() adds a dynamic function table; if there already is a static function table (.pdata section) for the base address, the RtlAddFunctionTable() calls succeeds, but the static function table still takes precedence.

You need to allocate memory outside the image range, e.g. using VirtualAlloc(), and have your code and runtime table and unwind info there. The address of allocated memory is the base address for all the RVAs in the tables, and needs to be passed to RtlAddFunctionTable().

You can experiment with RtlLookupFunctionEntry() to see if the function table entry is found for a given address.

Sample code showing RtlAddFunctionTable() in action is at https://pmeerw.net/blog/programming/RtlAddFunctionTable.html.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to register your handler with call to `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` (if you use SEH as stated in your post) or `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` (if you decide to switch to [VEH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420(v=vs.85).aspx))? In your code you add information about the handler but do not register it.

I have tested your sample with the change of the handler itself:

```
LONG WINAPI catchDivZero(EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionInfo)
{
    printf("Exception will be handled!\n");
    return ExceptionContinueSearch;
}
```

and adding the code:

```
if (::AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, catchDivZero))
{
    printf("Set exception handler.\nContinuing..\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Setting exception handler failed\n");
    DWORD result = GetLastError();
    printf("Error code: 0x%.8X\n", result);

    return 1;
}
```

just before the call to `RtlAddFunctionTable`.

Now the message from the handler is printed.

To remove the handler use:

```
::RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(catchDivZero);
```

Hope it helps.

***Note:*** as an alternative you may use `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(catchDivZero))`. Keep in mind that it's [not that useful for debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx):

> After calling this function, if an exception occurs in a **process that**
>   **is not being debugged**, and the exception makes it to the unhandled
>   exception filter, that filter will call the exception filter function
>   specified by the lpTopLevelExceptionFilter parameter.

With VEH way we can debug the handler function right in IDE, with SEH we can not (there is probably a solution to this but I do not know about it) so I've proposed VEH as the main solution.

Comment: I eventually went with VEH already. But I still don't know why the SEH handlers weren't working. Your example doesn't use the `SEH` handler at all since you register a `VEH` handler which gets hit. Unless i'm mistaken `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` sets 1 global unhandled exception filter where as `RtlAddFunctionTable` allows me to register a handler for a specific region of code. If I'm not mistaken, the one is not used to register a table function. http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net/docs/html/exception_handling.html

Comment: Check this link: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/support-requests/29/. Seems like it's a bug specific to mingw64.

Comment: Hmm, according to that it should have been solved once SEH was implemented in Mingw-w64. But it's still open so :?